# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n+n^2x^2}$ converge uniformly on $x\in(a,\infty )\; a\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

My Attempt:
The sequence $$< \frac{1}{n+n^2x^2}>$$ converges uniformly on $x\in(a,\infty ) \; a\geq 0$   to $0$.

But I have little confusion about series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n+n^2x^2}$$  How to show that series converges uniformly on $x\in(a,\infty )\; a\geq 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This series is not convergent at $x=0$. In fact it is not well defined (since for $n=0$ makes no sense).

Comment: The series does not converge at zero.  Since the series does not converge (pointwise) on $\Bbb R$, it cannot converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: and on $(0,\infty )$

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: My intuition says that it only converges unifomly on $[a,+\infty)$ for any $a>0$, but not in $(0,+\infty)$.
Only Intuition.

Comment: But how to show that.

Comment: On $[a,+\infty)$, $\frac{1}{n+n^2x^2}\le \frac{1}{n+n^2a^2}$ and the last series is converegent, so you can use Weierstrass M-test

Comment: What if we take $x_n=1/n$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$. Choose  a sequence $n_k$ with $n_{k+1} >2n_k+1$. Consider $\sup _x \sum\limits_{n=n_k+1}^{n_{k+1}} \frac 1 {n+n^{2}x^{2}} >\sum\limits_{n=n_k+1}^{n_{k+1}} \frac 1 { n_{k+1}+1}$ as seen by taking $x=\frac 1{\sqrt {n_{k+1}}}$. Hence $\sup _x \sum\limits_{n=n_k+1}^{n_{k+1}} \frac 1 {n+n^{2}x^{2}} >\frac 1 2$ for all $k$. This proves that the series is not uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$.

It may be noted that if $a>0$ then  for $x \geq a$ we have $\frac 1 {n+n^{2}x^{2}} \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}a^{2}}$. It follows that the series converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ for each $a >0$.

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{n+n^2 x^2}$- Does it changes your argument?

Comment: now what if $ (a,\infty)\; a\geq 0$

Comment: @TitoEliatron Actually my argument is for the correct function. I just made  a typo while posting the answer.

Comment: @AmitTikhe I have added a proof of uniform convergence for $x \geq a$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks